# NDSolve Surface Plot to Compare Initial Values

Tags: graphics, differential-equations, graphics3d, parametric-functions

I am trying to solve a system of differential equations which model reaction kinetics using NDSolve. I would like to generate a surface-plot of the function value as a function of time and the initial value of one of the functions. For example, suppose I want to solve

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == c}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

where c is a parameter that I vary. In my case, the solution can only be found numerically; no analytical solutions exist. I want a surface plot of y(t,c). Does anyone know of an easy way to do this? I haven't found much help online.

Comment: Have you seen `Plot3D[]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: `ParametricNDSolve`.

Comment: Your system of equations is a linear one and represents simple harmonic motion. In, fact, it has the analytical the analytical solution
$x=\cos t+c\sin t$. Now create a function of the two variables $t$ and $c$ and plot with `Plot3D`

Comment: To be clear; my system can not be solved analytically -- I gave an example to clarify my meaning, but it is not the system I am working with, and I don't think the output from NDSolve is compatible with Plot3D

ParametricNDSolve is more along the lines of what I am looking for; is there a version that lets you create a surface plot?

Comment: Well, you could use a slight change of march's suggestion; that is, look up `ParametricNDSolveValue[]`; you should be able to use that with `Plot3D[]`.

Comment: According to your equations,$y=x^{\prime }$, so that $x=-\sin t+c\cos t $. Then plot with `Plot3D[-Sin[t] + c Cos[t], {t, 0, 10}, {c, -2, 2}].` Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I can post an answer at this point (with a hat tip to march):

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == c},
                            y, {t, 0, 10}, c];

Plot3D[pf[c][t], {t, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 4}]
```

[image: plot of a parametrized numerical solution]

Comment: Does `ParametricNDSolveValue` still solve for both `x` and `y` under the hood, just returns only the solution for `y`?

Comment: I believe so (it's a coupled DE system after all); since only `y` was needed, this is reflected in the second argument of `ParametricNDSolveValue[]`.

Comment: It seems to give identical results either way, though I wouldn't trust MMA to *know* that the list of functions is `{x,y}` without explicitly being told so.